# Change chart size on print - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im trying to change the size of the chart on print, as part of the legend gets hidden by overflow. However i can't seem to get it to work.

Im using the exporting object and have tried setting height and width as well as sourceHeight and sourchWidth, but the size of the print never actually changes. I've also tried putting inside a nested chart object within exporting and that doesnt work either?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSize` method in `beforePrint` and `afterPring` events:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            beforePrint: function() {
                this.setSize(400, 400, false);
            },
            afterPrint: function() {
                this.setSize(null, null, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hnov1bdw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.afterPrint

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.beforePrint

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setSize